# Divide column values by a single other column value within same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to normalize values by another value within the same column. This is a biological experiment where treatment H is the control and treatments A-G are the experimental, and I want to get a relative value of experimental/control, on a per Target, Treatment and Time basis. Not sure how to do this with dplyr.

In the screenshot of my data, I want to take the values in the yellow box and divide each one by the value in the red box, and come up with a new derived variable, call it "Relative Value".

[image]

```
Target Treatment Time                mean      sd(Value)    n
<chr>   <chr>   <S3: POSIXct>        <dbl>     <dbl>       <int>
A       A       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2023.6667   192.289019  6
A       B       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2087.1667   179.314714  6
A       C       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2058.1667   149.807098  6
A       D       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2018.5000   129.040691  6
A       E       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2031.5000   155.547742  6
A       F       1899-12-31 00:10:00 1991.6667   146.535547  6
A       G       1899-12-31 00:10:00 2131.6667   138.959946  6
A       H       1899-12-31 00:10:00 1929.0000   232.428914  6
```

Comment: `mean / mean[[which(Treatment == "Q")]]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(`Relative Value` = mean / mean[Treatment=="H"])
```

Comment: ```summary_raw %>% filter(Target == "A") %>% arrange(Time, Target, Treatment) %>% mutate(norm = mean/mean[Treatment == "H"])``` gave ```Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `norm = mean/mean[Treatment == "H"]`.
ℹ In group 1: `Target = "A"`, `Treatment = "A"`.
Caused by error:
! `norm` must be size 56 or 1, not 0.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% mutate(norm = mean / mean[Treatment == "H"])
 9. dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)
Error in mutate(., norm = mean/mean[Treatment == "H"]) : 
ℹ In group 1: `Target = "A"`, `Treatment = "A"`.
Caused by error:
! `norm` must be size 56 or 1, not 0.```

Comment: @Alex, that will only happen if there is no `H` within that particular group. So you do expect the error, ie nothing to divide by.